# When do I need to declare class data members as public?

Tags: class, public

Is there any situation when I need to declare the class data members as public?
Are there any chances of errors with such declarations?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: There are probably many cases for this...it all depends on your scenario

Comment: Little helper structs with no encapsulation... Situations where quick access is critical and you can test if is possible to avoid the overhead of calling a method... It wildly depends on what you're doing, I think. Just read your edit... Chances of errors??. What do you mean?. Which language are you using?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Need to?** No.

Any data access can be done through getters and setters:
(the truth of the above statement may depend on the language)

```
private member

public getMember()
  return member

public setMember(newValue)
  member = newValue
```

Instead of

```
public member
```

**Errors?** No. Well, apart from having to change your code to use the getters and setters instead.

**Want to?** Possibly.

The main disadvantage of using getters and setters is how pretty your code looks - how readable it is and code bloating.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) for advantages of using getters and setters.

**If using getters and setters classifies as similar to making the member public** for you, then there are many scenario's where you need this at one of these kinds of access. Consider an artificial example of having a `Car` class. There would be many reasons why you'd want to get the `windscreen` member variable.